# Turning a function into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to turn a xml sitemap into a list. Ultimately, I don't know how to call each line. If I cant call e.g. `lst[0]`, `lst[1]` I cant scrape each link e.g. `title = (get_url()).findAll("div",{"class":"large-7 medium-9 columns"}[0].h1)`

Teach me the ways

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_urls():
    baseurl = 'https://link/sitemap.xml'
    request = requests.get(baseurl)
    response = str(request.content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    search_html = soup.find_all('url')
    results_list = [item.find('loc').decode().split('>', 1)[1].split('<', 1)[0].strip() for item in search_html]
    for url in results_list:
        retuned_objects(url)


def retuned_objects(url):
    print(format(url))

# i = []

# for i in get_urls():
# lnks

lst = [get_urls()]

print(lst[0])
```

Comment: Why not return list? Like return results_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just return `results_list`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_urls():
    baseurl = 'https://www.desertessence.com/sitemap.xml'
    request = requests.get(baseurl)
    response = str(request.content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    search_html = soup.find_all('url')
    results_list = [item.find('loc').decode().split('>', 1)[1].split('<', 1)[0].strip() for item in search_html]
    return results_list

lst = get_urls()

print(lst)
```